# Flatlist with Paginated Result Cause Rerender when Appending More Data Using Redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist, immutable.js, reducers

I am trying to display list of informations from server (paginated results) on react native using flatlist

The problem seems it always rerender the whole list when loading second batch of result.

The flatlist component

```
<FlatList
          data={_.size(this.props.search.getIn(['userInfoList','data'])) > 0 ? this.props.search.getIn(['userInfoList', 'data']).toJS() : []}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => this._renderResult(item, index)}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          ListFooterComponent={()=>this._flatlistLoader()}
          ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
          ListEmptyComponent={()=>this._emptyList()}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
          onEndReached={() => this.loadMore()}
          onRefresh={() => this.refreshList()}
          refreshing={this.props.search.userInfoList.isRefreshing}
          initialNumToRender={8}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
        />
```

shouldComponentUpdate function

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    return !_.isEqual(nextProps, this.props)
  }
```

_renderResult(item, index) function returning InfoBox pure component

```
_renderResult(item,index){
    return(
      <InfoBox key={index} item={item}/>
    )
  }
```

this is part of my action function after request data from server

```
if(res.status == 200){
                    let newArr = []
                    getState().search.getIn(['userInfoList','data']).map((val) => {
                      newArr.push(val)
                    })
                    res.json.data.data.map((val) => {
                      newArr.push(val)
                    })
                    
                    dispatch(setInfoListResult(newArr))
                  }
```

then the reducer looks like this

```
case SET_INFO_LIST_RESULT:
      return state.setIn(['userInfoList', 'data'], fromJS(action.newArr))
```

My Initial State
import {Record, List, Map} from 'immutable'

```
var InitialState = Record({
...
userInfoList: new (Record({
    userid:null,
        total: null,
        lastPage: null,
        data : [],
        perPage : null,
        currentPage : null,
        nextPageUrl: null,
        prevPageUrl:null,
        prevScene:null,
        isFetching:false,
        isRefreshing:false,
        hasError:false,
        hasMoreError:false,
        errorMsg:'',
    }))(),
})
```

I put console.log(item.id) inside InfoBox (PureComponent), when the flatlist start to load second page, it rerender the whole list 2 times and getting a warning

> VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make
> sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React
> performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate,
> etc.', { dt: 4913, prevDt: 2441, contentLength: 11064 }

Something wrong with how I update the list on reducer that causing the rerender? Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toJS()` converts an immutable collection to a **new** javascript object. So whenever your component runs `render()`, it generates a new object and triggers the FlatList's rendering.

Furthermore, toJS performs **deep** conversion. Your records are now plain mutable javascripts objects again. Use [toArray](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/toArray) if all you need is turning a collection into an array.

You should generally avoid converting collections anywhere, it renders immutablejs useless and is bad for performance on huge datasets. Of course, some components require you to use native arrays. You might want to use some kind of memoization for these cases, e.g. [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), memoize-one, [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect), [re-reselect](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/re-reselect)

to reduce the amount of calls to